# React useRef on Canvas getting null or undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to reference a canvas DOM element to make the width of it the same as its parent without messing with the scale of the canvas. When doing so I am getting a `Uncaught TypeError: _canvasRef$current.getContext is not a function` error and am not exactly sure how to fix it.

Ive console logged a few things just to make the app run but the issue is within the `useEffect`

```
import SignaturePad from 'react-signature-canvas'

const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)

useEffect(() => {
    const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null | undefined =
        canvasRef.current?.getContext('2d')
    const ctxContainer = document.getElementById('ctxContainer')

    console.log('ctx: ', ctx)
    // if (ctx && ctxContainer) {
    //     ctx.style.width = '100%'
    //     ctx.style.height = '100%'
    //     ctx.width = ctxContainer.clientWidth
    // }
}, [])

const save = () => {
    console.log('saved!')
}

console.log('canvasRef: ', canvasRef)

return (
    <div id={`ctxContainer`} className={'signatureInput__option-draw'}>
        <SignaturePad
            ref={canvasRef}
            canvasProps={{
                className: 'signatureInput__option-draw__canvas',
            }}
            onEnd={save}
        />
    </div>
)
```

Comment: It could be useful to provide the definition of your `SignaturePad` component

Comment: `import SignaturePad from 'react-signature-canvas'`

Comment: Does putting `canvasRef` in the useEffect update array help? Example: `useEffect(()=>{...}, [canvasRef])`

Comment: I tried that and I am still receiving that same error

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

> Note that you may still need to do some [changes](https://codesandbox.io/embed/resizing-canvas-with-react-hooks-gizc5) to following code to full fill your full requirement ( such as event handling when the user change the screen sizes. ) The following code will fix the issue you are facing right now.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current.getCanvas();
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // do something with the canvas ref
      if (ctx) {
        ctx.canvas.width = window.innerHeight;
        ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using getCanvas() . i dont think getContext() is provided with the package

```
function App() {
  const canvasRef = React.createRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    console.log(canvas.current);
    const ctx = canvas.getCanvas();
    const ctxContainer = document.getElementById("ctxContainer");

    console.log("ctx: ", ctx);
    if (ctx && ctxContainer) {
      ctx.style.width = "100%";
      ctx.style.height = "100%";
      ctx.width = ctxContainer.clientWidth;
    }
  }, []);

  const save = () => {
    console.log("saved!");
  };

  console.log("canvasRef: ", canvasRef);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id={`ctxContainer`} className={"signatureInput__option-draw"}>
        <SignaturePad
          ref={(ref) => {
            canvasRef.current = ref;
          }}
          canvasProps={{
            className: "signatureInput__option-draw__canvas",
          }}
          onEnd={save}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```